# Create a static listbox, or use a non static list box in a static method? C#

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, static, listbox

I am trying to get a ListBox to be static, or find a way to use a non-static ListBox in a static method. I have something like

```
private void static Add(string msg)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(msg)
}
```

and listBox1 is defined above as non static. However, when I change where the ListBox is being defined above to static, it causes more errors, thus not fixing the problem. Is it possible to create a static ListBox , or a way around this (without having to create a second class)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it why do you want to use this static method but I realized that if you change your method like this, it should works (of course sending listbox to the method is necessary):

```
    private static void send(ListBox listbox1, string msg)
    {
        listbox1.Items.Add(msg);
    }
```

EDIT:

Another way I found is:

In your Form1.Designer.cs (add at the bottom):

```
static System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox;
```

then in your Form1.cs constructor:

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1.listBox = this.listBox1;
    }
```

Now you can use your method properly - I think so.

Comment: I have already tried that. It does not work since the ListBox I am passing in is not static (same issue occurs).

Comment: Probably you should add the code that you have used to try this method and explain what is the error you get